# whereHas entre pivotes Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-6, relaciones

Hola tengo los siguientes modelos

```
class Region extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'regions';
    protected $fillable = [
        'country_id',
        'name',
    ];

    public function provinces()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Province::class);
    }

    public function communes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Commune::class, Province::class);
    }
}

class Province extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'provinces';
    protected $fillable = [
        'region_id', 
        'name'
    ];

    public function communes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Commune::class);
    }
}


class Commune extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'communes';
    protected $fillable = [
        'province_id', 
        'name', 
    ];

    public function province()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Province::class);
    }

    public function projects_web()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(WProject::class);
    }
}

class WProject extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'wprojects';
    protected $fillable = [
        'commune_id',
        'name',
        'inDS19',
    ];

    public function commune()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Commune::class);
    }

    public function models()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(HouseModel::class, 'project_id');
    }
}

class HouseModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'models';

    protected $fillable = [
        'project_id',
        'name'
    ];

    public function livingplaces(){
        return $this->hasMany(Livingplace::class, 'model_id');
    }

    public function project(){
        return $this->belongsTo(WProject::class);
    }
}
```

[image: Relacional]

Estoy intentando rescatar las regiones con sus proyectos y sus modelos donde los proyectos contengan el campo inDs19 en 1 con la siguiente consulta, pero solo me esta arrojando todas las regiones que tienen proyectos...

```
return Region::whereHas('communes', function($query) {
    return $query
        ->whereHas('projects_web', function ($query2) {
            return $query2
                ->where('inDS19', 1);
        });
})
->with('communes.projects_web.models')
->get();
```

Comment: Que modelos amigo ?? los puse al inicio del post